# IDictionary extension not actually running while in LInq Query .Where()

Tags: c#, linq, extension-methods, idictionary

I have an extension for an IDictionary that is meant to allow it to be case insensitive when doing a contains:

```
public static bool ContainsKeyIgnoreCase<TKey, TModel>(this IDictionary<TKey, TModel> dictionary, TKey key)
{
    bool? keyExists;

    var keyString = key as string;
    if (keyString != null)
    {
        keyExists =
            dictionary.Keys.OfType<string>()
            .Any(k => string.Equals(k, keyString, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
    }
    else
    {
        keyExists = dictionary.ContainsKey(key);
    }

    return keyExists ?? false;
}
```

But it never seems to run, hitting breakpoints or anything, while inside a .Where() :

```
public IEnumerable<TModel> PopulateIdsFromExistingRowsAndReturnNewRowsToCreate<TFromDBDto, TKey, TModel>(
    IEnumerable<TFromDBDto> fromDatabase,
    IDictionary<TKey, TModel> fromImport,
    Func<TFromDBDto, TKey> keySelector)
    where TFromDBDto : class, IGuidDataTransferObject
    where TModel : class, IModel<Guid>
{

    var groupedItems = fromDatabase
        .GroupBy(i => keySelector(i));
    var onlyKeys = groupedItems.Select(i => new { key = i.Key, value = i.First() });
    var filtered = onlyKeys.Where(i => fromImport.ContainsKeyIgnoreCase(i.key));
    var items = filtered.ToDictionary(i => i.key, i => i.value);

    var newItems = fromImport
        .Where(i => !items.ContainsKeyIgnoreCase(i.Key))
        .Select(i => i.Value);

    fromImport
        .Where(i => items.ContainsKeyIgnoreCase(i.Key))
        .ForEach(i => { i.Value.ID = items.AtKey(i.Key).ID; });

    return newItems;
}
```

However it will run if inside a for loop:

```
foreach(var keys in onlyKeys)
    {
        fromImport.ContainsKeyIgnoreCase(keys.key);
    }
```

Wondering if I'm doing something wrong or simply why it would refuse to actually run through the extension.

Comment: You can make .NET dictionaries have case insensitive keys by passing an appropriate equality comparer to the constructor: var myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);

Comment: I suspect you need to learn about [deferred execution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/introduction-to-linq-queries#query-execution).

Comment: it is because you are not interacting with enumerable, and the execution of where is delayed

Comment: @RikRak I know that I can do that but in this case the dictionary already exists when it is brought into this method, and I wouldn't be able to create the second dictionary with Linq. Which is fine, I have other options of making this work. Just trying to idnetify why the extension wont' work inside of the .Where().

Comment: @ZecosMAX wouldn't a breakpoint inside of the extension still trigger after the delay?

Comment: @Maxxxxxy yes, it will, the code should execute either way, if you would actually interact with enumerable

Comment: @ZecosMAX this is a small snippet of the overall code, I do interact with it eventually. But from what I am experiencing it never hits the breakpoint.

Comment: There can be other reasons code doesn't break; do something else more obvious; throw an exception in the extension for example. That should reassure you that it's running or not

Comment: @Maxxxxxy this seems strange, do you see any data in `newItems` when you interact with it later on? and do you use Debug build? as for a crude solution, you can follow an answer

Comment: @ZecosMAX I reset my VS and it seems to be working expectedly now. I have been in Debug build. I'm not sure what the issue was, but it seems to be working fine now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuing on my comment, and as @Kirk Woll pointed out, this is an example of a
"deferred execution". In simple words the execution of `Where` method is delayed until you would need that data.

In your case, you have following code:

```
    var newItems = fromImport
        .Where(i => !items.ContainsKeyIgnoreCase(i.Key))
        .Select(i => i.Value);

    fromImport
        .Where(i => items.ContainsKeyIgnoreCase(i.Key))
        .ForEach(i => { i.Value.ID = items.AtKey(i.Key).ID; });

    return newItems;
```

in this moment of execuion there is nothing that accessing the data itself, you do return it, but not interacting.

if you create and test this example (breakpoint is at return in where):

```
Dictionary<string, int> dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
dict.Add("a", 0);
dict.Add("b", 0);
dict.Add("c", 0);

dict.Add("A", 0);
dict.Add("B", 0);
dict.Add("C", 0);

var newItems = dict
    .Where(i => {
        return !dict.ContainsKeyIgnoreCase(i.Key);
    })
    .Select(i => i.Value);

Thread.Sleep(10000);

Console.WriteLine(newItems.Count());
```

you will see that the breakpoint will not be hit until 10 seconds mark
(loot at this screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKlWf.jpg)

As to you comment about breakpoint is never hit, make sure you return a reference to a enumerable rather than a copy, and if you actually interact with it.

As a crude solution, you could make this change to your code:

```
    var newItems = fromImport
        .Where(i => !items.ContainsKeyIgnoreCase(i.Key))
        .Select(i => i.Value)
        .ToList();
```

this will force the execution of your query, because data needs to be copied into new list

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing processing the query:

```
fromImport
    .Where(i => items.ContainsKeyIgnoreCase(i.Key))
    .ForEach(i => { i.Value.ID = items.AtKey(i.Key).ID; });
```

What is the definition of the ForEach() extenaion method?
It might be that the ForEach() is returning an iterator (IEnumerable<>); you need to do something with it to process the query.  For example:

```
var myStuff = fromImport
    .Where(i => items.ContainsKeyIgnoreCase(i.Key))
    .ForEach(i => { i.Value.ID = items.AtKey(i.Key).ID; })
    .ToList();  // <-- this will run the query
```